# How can I detect a word in a column variable and mutate it in a new column in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| var |
| --- |
| A_CAT |
| B_DOG |
| A_CAT |
| F_HORSE |
| GEORGE_DOG |
| HeLeN_CAT |

and I want to look like this :

| var | var_new |
| --- | --- |
| A_CAT | CAT |
| B_DOG | DOG |
| A_CAT | CAT |
| F_HORSE | HORSE |
| GEORGE_DOG | DOG |
| HeLeN_CAT | CAT |

How can I do this  in R ?

```
library(tidyverse)
var = c("A_CAT","B_DOG","A_CAT","F_HORSE","GEORGE_DOG","HeLeN_CAT")
df = tibble(var);df
```

Comment: What are the rules for extracting the substring?  Just whatever comes after the underscore?  What if you have "A_CAT_DOG"?  Or "CAT_A"?  Do you still want "CAT" extracted in each of those cases?

Comment: yes whatever contains the words CAT or DOG or HORSE after or before the underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
   mutate(var_new = str_remove(var, '.+_'))

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  var        var_new
  <chr>      <chr>  
1 A_CAT      CAT    
2 B_DOG      DOG    
3 A_CAT      CAT    
4 F_HORSE    HORSE  
5 GEORGE_DOG DOG    
6 HeLeN_CAT  CAT
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R base `sub`

```
> df$var_new <- sub(".*_(.*)$", "\\1", df$var)
> df
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  var        var_new
  <chr>      <chr>  
1 A_CAT      CAT    
2 B_DOG      DOG    
3 A_CAT      CAT    
4 F_HORSE    HORSE  
5 GEORGE_DOG DOG    
6 HeLeN_CAT  CAT
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `str_extract` to extract the desired srings, by using `(?i)` we could make the search case insensitive:

```
librar(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(var_new = str_extract(var, "(?i)CAT|Dog|Horse"))
```

```
         var var_new
1      A_CAT     CAT
2      B_DOG     DOG
3      A_CAT     CAT
4    F_HORSE   HORSE
5 GEORGE_DOG     DOG
6  HeLeN_CAT     CAT
```